# Linker error: undefined reference to... (member functions)

Tags: c++, vector, linker

I read many of the other questions about this linker error, but I still wasn't able to solve it yet...

vector.hpp

```
#ifndef vector_hpp
#define vector_hpp

namespace vec
{

template<class T> class Vector
{
private:
    T* arr;
    unsigned int numberOfElements;

public:
    Vector();
    ~Vector();
    void push_back(const T&);
    void pop_back();
    void pop_front();
    unsigned int size() const;
    T& at(int);
    T& front();
    bool empty() const;

    T& operator[](const int) const;
};

}


#endif
```

vector.cpp (not everything, would be too long)

```
#include "vector.hpp"
#include <iostream>

namespace vec
{

template<class T>
Vector<T>::Vector()
        : arr(nullptr), numberOfElements(0)
{
    return;
}

template<class T>
Vector<T>::~Vector()
{
    delete[] arr;
}

template<class T>
unsigned int Vector<T>::size() const
{
    return numberOfElements;
}

...
}
```

patientenliste.hpp

```
#ifndef patientenliste_hpp
#define patientenliste_hpp

#include "vector.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include "patient.hpp"

using namespace std;

class Patientenliste
{
private:
    vec::Vector<Patient> liste;

public:
    Patientenliste& operator+= (const Patient&);
    vec::Vector<Patient>& getPListe();

    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, const Patientenliste&);
};


ostream& operator<< (ostream&, const Patientenliste&);

#endif
```

patientenliste.cpp

```
#include "patientenliste.hpp"

Patientenliste& Patientenliste::operator+= (const Patient& p)
{
    liste.push_back(p);
    return *this;
}

vec::Vector<Patient>& Patientenliste::getPListe()
{
    return liste;
}

ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const Patientenliste& p)
{
    if(p.liste.size() == 0)
        os << "Keine Patienten in der Liste.";
    else
        for(unsigned int i=0; i < p.liste.size(); i++)
            os << p.liste[i] << endl;
    return os;
}
```

I have some more files/classes in my project but every class which uses my Vector-class I get the Linker-error:

patientenliste.cpp:(.text+0x32): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `vec::Vector<Patient>::size() const'
patientenliste.cpp:(.text+0x5e): Nicht definierter Verweis auf`vec::Vector::size() const'
patientenliste.cpp:(.text+0x6c): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `vec::Vector::operator [ ] (int) const'

(in english "Nicht definierter Verweis auf" means "undefined reference to")
I have absolutely no clue about what's going wrong... 
I already tried it wihtout the namespace vec, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Template definitions shall be in the same header file where the corresponding template class is defined.